# How to optimize a self-written blit function when one knows details about memory layout, etc.?

Tags: c++, memory, optimization

I had a programming test recently, and I wanted to get some information on a question I wasn't entirely sure about.

The first problem was to write a TransparentBlit function with the following notes:

> Assume that color data is stored in one byte, and that all data are in contiguous sections of memory in row-major order.  Assume that no out-of-bounds will be given.

I did that well enough, I figure, but there was a follow-up question:

> The previous function is largely dependent on the format of the memory.  Explain how it could be better optimized if you knew more details about the layout of memory, etc.

I didn't quite know how to respond to that, so I babbled a bit.  Could someone teach me what I need to know so I can better answer a problem like that in the future?

Comment: Wait a minute.. if the blt function wrote itself, why can't you just ask it to optimize itself?

Comment: Could you please give an example memory layout?

Comment: I think I know what this is about.  It's kind of a stupid question.  In the first part, you're supposed to write a function that calls getpixel in src and setpixel in dest.  When you know the memory layout, you can directly read 4/8/16 (however big your machine word size is) bytes at a time.  additionally, if you knew information about the memory management and caching unit, you can do more.  for example, interlacing memory banks.

Comment: @thang That's more or less the answer, I think.

Comment: @thang:

It's a function I wrote for a test, not for actual use.  Evidently the function can be optimized beyond the 

if(isTransparent(*srcPixel)) { destPixel++; srcPixel++; } else {*destPixel++ = *srcPixel++; } 

level if I knew more details about "the layout of memory, etc."  How, exactly, I don't know, and I'd like to learn.  You gave a half-example, saying that if I knew about memory layout (what do you mean?) I can read words instead of bytes; I think I see how that's faster.  What about memory management, caching unit, interlacing, etc, that you talked about?  I curious about specifics.

Comment: These are big topics.  Try here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interleaved_memory, here http://www.lamarca.org/anthony/caches.html, and here http://www.eetimes.com/design/signal-processing-dsp/4016948/Optimizing-for-cache-performance-part-2/